# edit text height getting decrease on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

I am having a editText and a listview in a single layout .But on clicking editText its height getting decrease like this

Before Click :

[image]

On Click :

[image]

Here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_clients_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/edbackground"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:drawablePadding="10.0dip"
        android:hint="search clients"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="15.0dip" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/clients_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and remove `android:layout_weight="0.9"` to `EditText`.

Comment: do like *M D* said it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove weight and put `wrap_content` for height of `EditText`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_clients_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="10.0dip"
        android:hint="search clients"
        android:textColor="#123456"
        android:textSize="15.0dip" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/clients_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This should work

Comment: please tell me What should  in place of wrap content

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha see my comment

Answer (score 2):

Just put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and also `remove android:layout_weight="0.9"` to `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your edittext, soft-input comes up and android adjust screen contents sometimes. This is reason your edittext is looking cropped. To prevent this, in your `Manifest.xml` where you have defined your activity, add following line in your `Activity` tag:-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

This will work.

Comment: I am using this layout in fragment . However I got my solution :)

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha that is good, maybe this will help someone else. :)